# Where is the GNOME Extensions error log?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have installed `gnome-shell-extension-move-clock` on 18.04 and it does not work.  In gnome-tweaks it displays a warning icon with the title "Error loading extension".

Where can I find more details about the exact error?  Is there a log file for the GNOME Extensions?